# Flutter: How to add outline/stroke border in IconButton?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to add outline/stroke border in IconButton?
I tried to use the stack but this doesn't give the output as expected.

this is my code

```
SliverAppBar(
            leading: Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              children: [
                Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_back,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  size: 36,
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: new Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_back,
                    size: 24,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            //
            // another code
            //
          ),
```

The Output from the code above

[image]

I want to create an outline/stroke in IconButton like Text on the right side of the output.

Example of icon with customizable 'outline/stroke border color' and fill color

[image]

I tried to find a solution but I couldn't find it. is it possible to customize IconButton by adding an outline/stroke border with code only?

Answer (score 5):

Depending on the icon, if it has an outlined/bordered version you could achieve this with a `Stack`.
Example:

```
IconButton(
    icon: Stack(
        children: [
            Icon(Icons.favorite, color: Colors.red),
            Icon(Icons.favorite_border, color: Colors.white),
        ],
    ),
    onPressed: () => {},
),
```

This would show a red heart with a white outline.

Answer (score 2):

As said by [@Rohan Thacker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67254688/13096991). At this time, flutter doesn't support the feature to add an outline/stroke border to an `icon`. So the best solution for customizing `icons`, in this case is to use an image with an `SVG` format (SVG format have smaller file size than .png or .jpg) and use the [flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) plugin to be able to use the `SVG` image assets as an `IconButton`.

So from the above case, I finished with code like this (using the [flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) plugin):

```
IconButton(
  icon: SvgPicture.asset(
    "assets/icons/ back-arrow-bold.svg",
    width: 30,           
  ),
  onPressed: (){},
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, currently flutter does not support this feature. The only decoration option available to an `Icon` is the `fill` color.

Flutter icons work by using a `.ttf` font with a `unicode codePoint` defined per symbol in the `Icon Font Family` unlike the `web` where an `SVG` is usually used and since most browsers support `svgs` natively we have the ability set an outline value to achieve the result shown above.

You can however achieve the result shown above with a `CustomPainter` and `CustomPaint` widget, but this would involve manually drawing the shape of your icon and then settings the `PaintStyle` property to `Stroke`.

[CustomPaint Docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html)

Comment: It seems it's too complex just to make an icon. Is CustomPaint the only solution to this problem?

Comment: Well through the core framework I believe CustomPainter is the only way.
There maybe a community plugin available that does the task, but I don't know of any at this time.

Comment: Do consider marking this answer as the accepted answer,  so that we can help anyone else with the same question on the StackOverflow community

Comment: I answer my own question by providing a solution. But it's good to know that the above cases can also be solved using the `CustomPaint` widget. So I will accept your answer. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your gonna need some design acumen here :

1. Go https://icons8.com
2. Select the icon you want to.
3. Click on add effect then click on stroke.
4. Select the color of the stroke which is just fancy for border color.
5. Download image and use as your icon

Answer (score 0):

A new alternative, though still not an outline, is to use the `shadows` property of `Icon`:

```
Icon(
    Icons.arrow_forward_rounded,
    color: Colors.blue,
    shadows: const [
        Shadow(
            color: Colors.white, 
            blurRadius: 2.0,
        ),
    ],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding another answer, as both are sort of valid, and this is the one I ended up using.

If your use case is about arrows - most fonts include symbols for arrows - So I just added to the text an arrow symbol, and the outline effect worked as desried!

[image: symbol viewer on macos]

See result here:

[image]