# How can I control the Stoke ( thikness ) of the icons

Tags: flutter

when we put an Icon Like this

```
          Icon(
              Icons.notifications_outlined,
            )
```

we can control the size and color... of that icon, but I want to control the Stroke width of the Icon (not the size of the icon, I want to control the width of the icon's line )

is it possible by any widget or any other way in flutter SDK?

please don't recommend packages of other icons

thanks

Comment: Already answered question. Refer the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67254237/flutter-how-to-add-outline-stroke-border-in-iconbutton).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any way from the flutter SDK to control the icons thinkers, I tried using `CustomPainter`, `BoxShadow()`...

alternatively, I used a different icons package which is the `Ionicons`, which belongs to the Ionic framework, I found out that there is a flutter package for those icons, see [Ionicons](https://pub.dev/packages/ionicons)

you can see a list of all icons here, https://ionic.io/ionicons

and they can be used like this:

```
Icon(Ionicons.add)
Icon(Ionicons.add_outline)
Icon(Ionicons.add_sharp)
```